# inserting multiple rows in a single table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

i would like to know how to insert multiple rows in a single table,i am trying these commands below but im getting errors

```
insert all
into hr.dean (id,first_name,last_name,phone_number,room_number,faculty,kafedra) values ('3','zulu','smart','+7905487265','421','airsapce','mathematics')
into hr.dean (id,first_name,last_name,phone_number,room_number,faculty,kafedra) values ('4','hendrix','mumba','+7805454721','521','mechanics','physics')
into hr.dean (id,first_name,last_name,phone_number,room_number,faculty,kafedra) values ('5','banda','edward','+260966645820','411','mechanics','chemistry')
into hr.dean (id,first_name,last_name,phone_number,room_number,faculty,kafedra) values ('6','nkoseman','lone','+260966665821','200','computers','informatics')
select from dual;
```

is there any way i can do this?or where am i making my mistakes?thanks in advance
this is the error im getting

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
insert all
into hr.dean (id,first_name,last_name,phone_number,room_number,faculty,kafedra) values ('3','zulu','smart','+7905487265','421','airsapce','mathematics')
into hr.dean (id,first_name,last_name,phone_number,room_number,faculty,kafedra) values ('4','hendrix','mumba','+7805454721','521','mechanics','physics')
into hr.dean (id,first_name,last_name,phone_number,room_number,faculty,kafedra) values ('5','banda','edward','+260966645820','411','mechanics','chemistry')
into hr.dean (id,first_name,last_name,phone_number,room_number,faculty,kafedra) values ('6','nkoseman','lone','+260966665821','200','computers','informatics')
select from dual
Error at Command Line:6 Column:7
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: @kryticrecte - You state that you are "getting errors".  It would be very helpful to specify what errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select something from DUAL, you can't use it like this.

do:

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```